# Pagination for records from CSV

Tags: visualforce, csv, pagination

I have a requirement where am getting collection of records from another method as list  which are not inserted in object(gettting from CSV), and i want display that list in visualforce page with pagination where we are providing ediability. How i can achieve pagination in this scenario?

Comment: This depends on the size of the list. If the CSV contains lots of data you have to use Apex to divide the data read from the file. If it's not much data, you can use some javascript framework to do it, for instance the JQuery plugin DataTables: https://datatables.net/

Comment: Inn my case it is having large data. how i can divide the data which am getting as list?. Here we are proving one fields of records as editable.

Comment: There are multiple options. You could just put the list in a variable in your controller (hoping that you won't hit the view state size limit) and use an offset variable to return parts of the list to use in an `apex:repeat` or something like that.

Comment: @lex Am not using soql so how i can use OFFSET here?

Comment: I didn't mean OFFSET in SOQL, but just a custom variable with which you can split the list. Search google for something like "apex list pagination" and I'm sure you'll find something.